# Why GraphicsMagick 1:1 color exchange with opaque & fill not work?

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I try exchange one color in my png with node + GraphicsMagick.

My code:

```
const gm = require('gm');

gm('./in.png').fill('black').opaque('#ccffff').write('./out.png', (err) => {
        console.log("recolored file saved");
});
```

This script changes not only the color but also the content of the image!

How can I change the color only?

[image: in.png]
in.png

[image: out.png]
out.png

Comment: I think the problem is this (see documentation):  The color is replaced if it is identical to the target color, or close enough to the target color in a 3D space as defined by the Euclidean distance specified by -fuzz
The destination color is by default no sharp!
But how can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you have the 'black' and '#ccffff' swapped. The fill color is the new color and opaque color is the color to be replaced. You have no  '#ccffff' in your image, but you do have black. You show only one image. Is that the input or output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This color exchange 1:1 you can't do in gm (or imagemagick) there is another concept (details: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace)

But you can this convert pixel by pixel:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;

console.log("run convert ...")

fs.createReadStream('./in.png')
    .pipe(new PNG())
    .on('parsed', function() {

        for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
                var idx = (this.width * y + x) << 2;

                // exchange color
                if(this.data[idx] == 204 && this.data[idx+1] == 255 && this.data[idx+2] == 255){
                    this.data[idx] = 255; // R
                    this.data[idx+1] = 0; // G
                    this.data[idx+2] = 0; // B
                }

            }
        }

        this.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.png'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Note sure I understand the question, but if you do the following with **ImageMagick**, you'll get what I expect:

```
magick image.png -fill magenta -opaque "rgb(204,255,255)" result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Why this not work in gm? I think gm an magic have the same concept. Your magic-statement make a 1:1 mapping an my gm-statement not!!!